# I can't get Hadoop to start using Amazon EC2/S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hadoop

I have created an AMI image and installed Hadoop from the Cloudera CDH2 build. I configured my core-site.xml as so:

```
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>s3://<BUCKET NAME>/</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value><ACCESS ID></value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value><SECRET KEY></value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/${user.name}</value>
 </property>
```

But I get the following error message when I start up the hadoop daemons in the namenode log:

```
2010-11-03 23:45:21,680 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check     fs.default.name): s3://<BUCKET NAME>/ is not of scheme 'hdfs'.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1015)

2010-11-03 23:45:21,691 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

However, I am able to execute hadoop commands from the command line like so:

```
hadoop fs -put sun-javadb-common-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm s3://<BUCKET NAME>/

 hadoop fs -ls s3://poc-jwt-ci/
Found 3 items
drwxrwxrwx   -          0 1970-01-01 00:00 /
-rwxrwxrwx   1      16307 1970-01-01 00:00 /sun-javadb-common-10.5.3-0.2.i386.rpm
drwxrwxrwx   -          0 1970-01-01 00:00 /var
```

You will notice there is a `/` and a `/var` folders in the bucket. I ran the hadoop namenode -format when I first saw this error, then restarted all services, but still receive the weird `Invalid URI for NameNode address (check     fs.default.name): s3://<BUCKET NAME>/ is not of scheme 'hdfs'.`

I also notice that the file system created looks like this:

```
 hadoop fs -ls s3://<BUCKET NAME>/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/mapred/system
Found 1 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1          4 1970-01-01 00:00 /var/lib/hadoop0.20/cache/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info
```

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Is the implementation for S3 setup in configuration as a filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I suggest you just use Amazon Elastic MapReduce. There is zero configuration required on your end. EMR also has a few internal optimizations and monitoring that works in your benefit.

Second, do not use s3: as your default FS. First, s3 is too slow to be used to store intermediate data between jobs (a typical unit of work in hadoop is a dozen to dozens of MR jobs). it also stores the data in a 'proprietary' format (blocks etc). So external apps can't effectively touch the data in s3.

Note that s3: in EMR is not the same s3: in the standard hadoop distro. The amazon guys actually alias s3: as s3n: (s3n: is just raw/native s3 access).

Comment: Does EMP scale well for larges amount of data? I am new to it, and thought S3 would be best for storing larges amounts of data, and setting up a cluster of AMIs to process it.

Comment: I run 200+ node clusters on EMR frequently. all durable/authoritative data is kept on s3 quite efficiently. all intermediate data is kept on hdfs until i destroy the cluster when the jobs are done. so yes, it scales well. (EMR runs on EC2, you just don't need to deal with any of it if you don't want)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not execute `bin/hadoop namenode -format`, because it is used for format the hdfs. In the later version, hadoop has move these functions in a separate scripts file which called "bin/hdfs". After you set the configuration parameters in core-site.xml and other configuration files, you can use S3 as the underlying file system directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Apache Whirr](http://whirr.apache.org/) for this workflow like this:

1. Start by downloading the latest release (0.7.0 at this time) from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/whirr/
2. Extract the archive and try to run `./bin/whirr version`. You need to have Java installed for this to work.
3. Make your Amazon AWS credentials available as environment variables:

   ```
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... 
   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
   ```
4. Update the Hadoop EC2 config to match your needs by editing `recipes/hadoop-ec2.properties`. Check the [Configuration Guide](http://whirr.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration-guide.html) for more info.
5. Start a cluster Hadoop by running:

   ```
   ./bin/whirr launch-cluster --config recipes/hadoop-ec2.properties
   ```
6. You can see verbose logging output by doing `tail -f whirr.log`
7. Now you can login to your cluster and do your work.

   ```
   ./bin/whirr list-cluster --config recipes/hadoop-ec2.properties
   ssh namenode-ip
   start jobs as needed or copy data from / to S3 using distcp
   ```

For more explanations you should read the [Quick Start Guide](http://whirr.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start-guide.html) and the [5 minutes guide](http://whirr.apache.org/docs/latest/whirr-in-5-minutes.html).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the committers.

Comment: Quick Start Guide and the 5 minutes guide are dead links now.

Comment: I have updated the links. The structure changed a bit after graduation from the incubator.

Answer (score 0):

Use

fs.defaultFS = s3n://awsAccessKeyId:awsSecretAccessKey@BucketName in your /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

Then do not start your datanode or namenode, if you have services that need your datanode and namenode this will not work..

I did this and can access my bucket using commands like
sudo hdfs dfs -ls /

Note if you have awsSecretAccessKey's with "/" character then you will have to url encode this.

Answer (score 0):

Use s3n instead of s3.

```
hadoop fs -ls s3n://<BUCKET NAME>/etc
```